# Change Date value format after fetching value inside the node

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the format of the Date value inside a node once I get the data. The code below fetches each specific value inside the node

```
foreach ($degreePrograms as $key => $program) {
    $programNode = _nodeLoad($program);

    $variables['degree_programs'][$key]['title'] = $programNode->get('title')->value;
    $variables['degree_programs'][$key]['body']  = $programNode->get('body')->value;
    $variables['degree_programs'][$key]['date'] = $programNode->get('field_start_date')->value;
    $variables['degree_programs'][$key]['link'] = $programNode->toUrl();
}
```

---

This code fetches the Date value inside the node and returns with a numbered date form `2017-09-04`. How can convert it to `March 04, 2017` instead

```
$variables['degree_programs'][$key]['date'] = $programNode->get('field_start_date')->value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
 $timestamp = strtotime($programNode->get('field_start_date')->value);
 $new_date_format = date('F j, Y', $timestamp);
```